# Why changing && to || is causing a variable to not be seen

Tags: java, file, loops, while-loop

I'm doing some practice with reading files and I've been tasked with writing File Interleave code for unbalanced files. So If I have things set up like this it works fine:

```
while ((inputLine1 = LineSequential.read(inFileStreamName1)) != null **&&** (inputLine2 = LineSequential.read(inFileStreamName2)) != null)
```

Note the &&... but If I change it to || netbeans states that the inputLine2 has not been initialized (though it sees inputLine1 perfectly fine this way):

```
while ((inputLine1 = LineSequential.read(inFileStreamName1)) != null **||** (inputLine2 = LineSequential.read(inFileStreamName2)) != null)
```

Right now, if inputLine1 (this is data from File A) becomes null first, I only get every other line in inputLine2 (from File B).  On each loop iteration its skipping a line. I'm fairly certain it has to do with where I initialize inputLine2..:

```
while ((inputLine1 = LineSequential.read(inFileStreamName1)) != null || LineSequential.read(inFileStreamName2) != null) {           
    inputLine2 = LineSequential.read(inFileStreamName2);
    System.out.println(inputLine2);
    if(inputLine1 != null && inputLine2 == null){
    LineSequential.write(outFileStreamName, inputLine1);
    }else if(inputLine1 == null && inputLine2 != null){
        LineSequential.write(outFileStreamName, inputLine2);
    }
    else if(inputLine1 != null && inputLine2 != null){
       LineSequential.write(outFileStreamName, inputLine1);
       LineSequential.write(outFileStreamName, inputLine2); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `||` is short-circuiting. Try `|` instead.

Comment: That got it! Thanks! One silly little line.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If a Boolean expression's value can be determined by the result of one operand, the second is not evaluated.

In this example, you're changing between `&&` and `||`. For an `&&` expression to be true, both sides must be true, so both sides are evaluated if the first is true (it would short-circuit if the first were false). For an `||` expression, at least one of the conditions must be met; since the first is true, it doesn't matter what the second one is, so it is not evaluated.

If you invert the truthiness of the left side, you'll observer the opposite: your `||` expression will work as you expect, but your `&&` expression will result in `inputLine2` not being initialized.

Answer (score 4):

Java does [lazy/short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). When you change to `||` all it cares about is making sure one is true. If the first conditional is true, it stops looking at the rest of the conditionals, making that variable null.

A good rule of thumb is to never initialization variables inside of conditionals, things can get messy.